# Aligning numbers with several different currency symbols in siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have the following list of prices:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{rl}
  US  & \$5.00\\
  CAN & \$6.50\\
  UK  & \textsterling4.00\\
  EU  & \texteuro4.50\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

As can be seen, the dollar, pound sterling, and euro signs all have different widths, leading to misalignment. The information I have seen for `siunitx` seems to assume that leading or following text (e.g. for units, currency, etc) is of the same width. However, in this case that obviously isn't an option.

Comment: What is your question? How to align the right column?

Comment: Yes, aligning to the right column to the decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `siunitx` here because your table alignment is `l`.  Anyway, since all your entries have exactly two digits after dot, just use `r` to roughly align the numbers:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{rr}
  US  & \$5.00\\
  CAN & \$6.50\\
  UK  & \textsterling4.00\\
  EU  & \texteuro4.50\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]